# declare pointer in if statement

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

I have declared the following variables

```
char min[6] = "";
char max[6] = "";
char hr[6] = "";
char div[6] = "";
char vol[6] = "";
```

and with the following code I get some tokens with strtok

```
if (pos)
    {

         ptr = strtok(buff, "Nodo_,=:V()");
         i = 0;
       while (ptr != NULL)
         {
          if (i == 0)
             strcat(min, ptr); 
          if (i == 2)
             strcat(tmax, ptr); 
          if (i == 4)
             strcat(hr, ptr); 
          if (i == 6)
             strcat(div, ptr);
          if (i == 8)
             strcat(vol, ptr); 

          ptr = strtok(NULL, "Nodo_,=:V()");
          i++;
         }
      printf("Results: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", min, max, hr, div, vol);
```

and the results are something like

```
Results: 4, 23, 45, 67, 89
```

I would like to create an if statement that will do the following(where s is the localtime)

```
char *table1[10] = {0};
        if(*min == "4")
        {
        table1[5]=min;
        table1[6]=max;
        table1[7]=hr;
        table1[8]=div;
        table1[9]=vol;
        fprintf(ft,"%s   %d   %d   %d   %d   %s   %s   %s   %s   %s",s,table1[0],table1[1],table1[2],table1[3],table1[5],table1[6],table1[7],table1[8],table1[9]);
        }
        else
        {
        table1[0]=min;
        table1[1]=max;
        table1[2]=hr;
        table1[3]=div;
        table1[4]=vol;
        fprintf(ft,"%s   %s   %s   %s   %s   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d",s,table1[0],table1[1],table1[2],table1[3],table1[5],table1[6],table1[7],table1[8],table1[9]);

        }
```

The problem is that I do not know how to write the if statement to compare with the value 4. I used different ways but I always have results in ELSE only

```
if(*min == "4")
if(*min == '4')
if(&min == "4")
   etc.
```

And secondly can you please propose me a better way to write this terrible fprintf which I have? Because I want my results in this way:

```
0 0 0 0 4 23 45 67 89
```

or

```
5 23 45 67 89 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: use strcmp for string comparisons; all == does in your case is compare memory locations.

Comment: @Bathsheba: write your comment as an answer, mate :)

Comment: @Binayaka Chakroborty: feel free to add answer; a good answer for this needs to be comprehensive.

Comment: `ptr = strtok(buff, "Nodo_,=:V()");` looks like you misunderstand `strtok`. The second argument is a list of delimiter characters, listing `'o'` twice is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems in your code.

1st. You are comparing strings in a VERY dangerous manner, to say the least. It could work in some strange cases. Generally it should be considered wrong.
In `c` you should use an appropriate function like `strcmp` or similar.

2nd. Your `fprintf(...)`s look exactly the same except for the expected type in the format strings (`%s` or `%d`). However, the type of `table1` does not chage! Using wrong specifiers can lead  from strange output observeed, to some hard to find memory bugs. To me it looks like you should always use `%s`. becasue its all `char*` type.
Also to simplify the print I guess you can use a simple `for` loop.

3rd. your `if`'s could be switched to more appropriate `case` or at least `if else`, since you will never execute two branches in one pass there. But its less important as it will not chage the overall logic. It could be performance critical in some situations.

EDIT:

OK, your `if` can be written in two ways.

`char *table[10] = {0};` This creates a table of pointers to 10 strings. You still need to further reserve space to actually hold characters. Also, `table1[5]=min;` will not put/copy string `min` into slot 5 of `table1`. It is the same mistake as with `==` and `strcmp`. You should probably read a short intro/tutorial on working with string in `c`.

You would need something more like:

```
char *table[10] = {0}; //create a table with pointers to 10 "strings"
size_t MAX_STR_SIZE = 6; // I assumed this from your example code.
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  table[i] = malloc(MAX_STR_SIZE); //allocate space for string
  //initialize
  table[i][0] = '0';  //put '0' into as 1st char
  table[i][1] = '\0'; //put null character at 2nd space 

  //table[i][0] = '\0'; // You can use this line or the one below this to initialize it
  //table[i][0] = 0;    // to a nullstring like you did in your 1st code snippet
}
```

then you can go to your if

```
if(strcmp(min,"4") == 0)
{
  strcpy(table[5], min); //This is how you copy null terminated strings in `c`.
  strcpy(table[6], max); 
  strcpy(table[7], hr);
  //...
} else {...}
fprintf(ft,"%s  ", s);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ 1) fprintf(ft,"%s  ", table[i]);
```

This will not reproduce all of your code but should get you to a point where its only a simple downhill ride.

EDIT2:

I thought you want to avoid using the `min,max` etc. and just switched it to tables. My bad. You can of course use table and re-use those pointers, to avoid unnecessary copying strings as i suggested earlier. However `table[i]` must always contain a proper pointer, to proper strings. I.e. not a null-pointer, and not a pointer to some random memory garbage. I would suggest something like:

```
char default_str[1] = ""; // or default_str[2] = "0" depending on your needs.
char *table[10] = {0}; //create a table with pointers to 10 "strings"
//...
if(*min == "4")
{
  table[0]=table[1]=table[2]=table[3]=table[4]=default_str;
  table[5]=min;
  table[6]=max;
  table[7]=hr;
  table[8]=div;
  table[9]=vol;
}
else
{
  table[5]=table[6]=table[7]=table[8]=table[9]=default_str;
  table[0]=min;
  table[1]=max;
  table[2]=hr;
  table[3]=div;
  table[4]=vol;
}
fprintf(ft,"%s  ", s);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ 1) fprintf(ft,"%s  ", table[i]);
```

This way, you set unused pointers to refer to the the `default_str`. It it closer to your original code now an uses less memory, as `table` entries "share" memory with original variables.

You could probably also use `char *table[10] = {default_str}`, and then skip re-initializing it within `if` branches, but I am not sure if `c` compilers would allow it.

Comment: `char *table[10] = {0};` **is** the definition of an array (named `table`) of 10 `char*`, all of them initialised to a null pointer.

Comment: @DanielFischer My bad. Of course you are right, I am sorry! However, the rest of statements hold (I hope). You need to allocate space for the strings themselves (probably might be done with `char table[10][6]`). And certainly `strcpy` is way to go for copying the strings. I also think I figured out what OP wanted to achieve, so I'll add second code-snippet that avoids `strcpy`. Thanks for poiting out the mistake.

Comment: Well, whether `table[0] = min;` is fine, or an allocation and `strcpy` is required depends on the use case. For the printing the OP does, a simple pointer assignment is enough (and the `%d` conversions need a cast to `int`, of course, but those apparently could be removed and replaced with a 0 digit in the format string) - if I guessed correctly what the OP wants to do there. But the whole thing looks strange.

Comment: Hmmm....With your example I have an error in strcpy like 'cannot convert 'char**' for argument '1' to char* strcpy(....)'

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure if OP wants '0' there or `\0`. Actually I changed it to `default_str` in 2nd example.

Comment: From the desired output, it looks like 0, `fprintf(ft, "%s    0    0   0    0   0    %s    %s    %s    %s\n", s, table[5],...)` or so. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @dali1985 try with 2nd example it is closer to your code and better overall. Also notice i changed `table1` to `table`, be sure to get everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since a string in C is actually an array of characters, and since all array variables in C are pointers, then when you do a comparison of the style `*min == "4"` you are actually comparing whatever is contained in the first position of `min` with whatever location the constant string `"4"` is given.

In order to perform string comparison you must use function [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), which is meant for that purpose.

If you want a cleaner way of printing your output, then you can save your result strings in a `char **` array and then print them using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

USE [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) or [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/), and arguments are char* so you have  to make for example 
if (strcmp(min,"4") ==0)

Notice that you have to to include string.h (i think you ve done this to use strcat )

PS: your lines such as  table1[5]=min; would not work because Table1[5] is a char while min is char*

Answer (score 0):

To compare you must use strcmp or strncmp since you are comparing char*.
You should't do `*min` because, `min` is a `char*` so when you are doing `*min == "4"` you are trying to compare the ascii value of the first character of min `(*min == min[0])`.
When you are trying to compare with one digit it's fine but if you trying to compare a number with multiple digits it's not going to work.

Then to display in a nice way don't use %d to display 0 since you are trying to display NULL
but you can do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 if (table1[i] == NULL)
   fprintf(ft, "0 ");
else
   fprintf(ft, "%s ", table1[i]);
}
fprintf(ft, "\n");
```

and when you fill your tab maybe you can try something like (in the loop of the strtok)

```
 while (ptr != NULL)
     {
       if (i%2 == 0)
         tab1[i / 2] = strdup(ptr); //don't forget to free at the end ;)
       i++;
     }
```

But if you are only manipulating numbers you can use a simple `int*` (`int tab1[10]`) and fill it with `atoi`

```
 while (ptr != NULL)
     {
       if (i%2 == 0)
         tab1[i / 2] = atoi(ptr); //
       i++;
     }
```

And in this case you can directly compare with number and do directly

```
if (tab1[i] == 4)
 ...
```